# How fast must a penny roll to remain upright?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I solved this question, however my professor's answer is different from mine.

I modelled the penny as circular disc of radius $a$ so its moment of inertia is: $$I_s = \frac{ma^2}{2}$$ so $$I = \frac{I_s}{2}$$ by perpendicular axis theorem.

So $$S^2 > \frac{mgl}{I_s}\frac{I}{I_s} = \frac{g}{a}$$ where $S$ is the angular velocity and $l=a$ is the location of the centre of mass. To get $v$ we have to note that $v = aS$ by the no-slipping condition, so we must have $$v^2 > a^2S^2$$

However my professor's answer has the following in it $$S^2 > \frac{mga}{2\frac{ma^2}{2} + ma^2}$$ I don't understand how he got that, can someone explain please?

Comment: This interesting question would benefit from some editing. What do $S$ and $l$ stand for, for instance?

Comment: S is the spin and l is the location of center of mass.

Comment: I've tried to clean things up a bit, some of your math seemed dubious (where did that 8 come from? might want to check that). I also tried to clarify what all the symbols mean, please check that these match your definitions.

Comment: I have a penny standing upright on my desk right now.  It is not rolling at all.  Maybe your penny does not have a squared-off edge like mine has.

Comment: $\frac{mgl}{I_s} = \frac{mgl}{\frac{ma^2}{2}} = \frac{mga}{\frac{ma^2}{2}} = \frac{2*g}{a}$
and we have 

$\frac{I}{I_s} = \frac{1/4 * ma^2}{1/2ma^2} = 2$ so yeah that suppose to be 4g/a

Comment: What you cite as your professor's answer, $S^2 > \frac{mga}{2\frac{ma^2}{2} + ma^2}$, actually works our as $S^2 > \frac{g}{2a}$, only a factor 2 away from your own $S^2 > \frac{g}{a}$. Looks like some typo causing problems here.

Comment: You appear to be using some standard result (your expression for $S^2$) without justification (presumably this came from your notes). It might be worth explaining where that comes from. Also, what does "ramin upright" mean? I know that a penny can roll around in a circle at a slight angle, helped in part by its finite edge thickness. Is your penny "ideal" (sharp edge)? A bit more definition might help.

Comment: A penny can stay upright when not moving.  I get the feeling that the stated problem assumes a penny which is rolling **and** has some tilt.  Is this the case?